# MySQL allow to select column that is neither aggregate nor specified in group by. Can this behavior be disabled?

Tags: mysql

It seems to me like `MySQL` is setting up a subtle trap for me. It allows to select column that is neither aggregate function like `sum` nor specified in `group by` clause. Therefor value in that column from my point of view is totally random.

I think in `Oracle` database that wasn't possible (but I used it like 5 years ago so something might change in this regard).

Is there any way to prevent from such nasty/trap-a-like behavior or at least tell it to warn me? Tools should work with developer not set up traps.

I'm using MySQL 5.6.30 and MySQL Workbench 6.3.7

Comment: Could you give us the query and the results it gives? Could be a simple tweak that could help you get rid of your paranoia that mysql is out to get you.

Comment: @LaurentMeganck Let's take simplest case there is order  with order lines, we are sum line price per order, let's say someone forgot to put `sum()` on price column when grouping. In that case there is glitch which might be hard to spot which can be simply avoid by make it more "strict" in regard to check whether column is either in `group by` or in `sum`

Comment: I can't understand what such behavior as described above might be even useful to. It's just subtle trap...

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you describe is known. MySQL gives the correct result set for any valid and sane query. It can return unexpected data on queries that make no sense.